# iphone/ios adHoc distribution crashing (shut down only in case of adHoc distribution)

Tags: iphone, ios, ad-hoc-distribution, application-shutdown

I've made an app using the Facebook API. I completed it, and there's no problem at all when I run my app on my device with development code signing.

So, I tried making it with adHoc distribution code signing and building was succeeded. There's also no problem when it goes through any other functions.

But when I try to share something to Facebook (using Facebook dialog API), this app shut down even though it worked well in case of development code sign on my device.

I can't debug cause this is adHoc version, so I don't know what the problem is. Can you let me know what the problem is?
When does this happen in what case?

Answer (score 2):

What's the problem? Delete the app from your device, then install the ipa with itunes to your device. Then, while your device is still connected, go to Xcode => Organizer => Devices => your device => Console and start your app on your device. Then you should see the reason for the crash.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I resolved this problem with debugging that you mentioned. I had not known the device debugging before , so was not easy to figure out the exact problem at that time.

Comment: Can you explain what was the problem?! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I checked the Device logs via `Xcode > Window > Devices > View Device Logs`.

The problem for me was that I am using a custom font which is integrated into my project via CocoaPods. During development time, the app runs smoothly because my computer can see where the font files are. However, Xcode doesn't bundle the font files (.ttf) from the pod into the project, so I had to either:

- Add the font files into Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources and adding the font files into my main project folder (without copying them; only as references).
- Or, remove the custom font as a CocoaPods dependency and copy-paste the font files to my project instead.

I went with the second one since I might accidentally delete one of the references to the font files and encounter the problem again.